# SSIS custom destination component - Where do I Create ExternalMetaData Columns

Tags: ssis, components, external

I've created a custom SSIS destination component to write to an MQ. I'm changing the code as I go using a test SSIS package to confirm it works.

I've got it all working where it maps the Message to the input column. All good. However I'm creating the ExternalMetadataColumnCollection in ProvideComponentProperties. I only realised when I started a new test package that this is the wrong place to call it. Now when I try to add the new component to the package I get an error

```
Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: The property is read-only.

Error at Data Flow Task [IBM MQ Destination Jo [6]]:   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0xC0204013): Exception from HRESULT: 0xC0204013
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSExternalMetadataColumn100.set_ID(Int32 pID)
   at   IBMWebsphereMQ.DestinationAdapters.IbmMQDestinationAdapter.CreateInputAndMetaDataColumns (IDTSInput100 input)
   at
```

IBMWebsphereMQ.DestinationAdapters.IbmMQDestinationAdapter.ProvideComponentProperties()
       at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostProvideComponentProperties(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)

Obviously ProvideComponentProperties is not the right place to create teh ExternalMetaData columns. Where should I be calling it?

Below is the code for the component

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Transactions;
using MyProject.IBMWebsphereMQ.ConnectionManagers;
using MyProject.IBMWebsphereMQ.Framework;
using MyProject.IBMWebsphereMQ.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using MyProject.IBMWebsphereMQ.MQ;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;


    namespace MyProject.IBMWebsphereMQ.DestinationAdapters
    {
    [DtsPipelineComponent(ComponentType = ComponentType.SourceAdapter,
     DisplayName = "IBM MQ Destination Jo",
     Description = "Writes messages to the defined queue",
     IconResource = "Dts.Pipeline.SSISSourceAdapter.source.ico",
     CurrentVersion = 1
     )]

    public class IbmMQDestinationAdapter : PipelineComponent, IEnlistmentNotification
    {
    private const string QueuePropertyName = "Queue";
    private const string BatchWriteSize = "BatchWriteSize";
    private const string ConnectionName = "IBM MQ connection";

    private const string MessageInputName = "Message";
    private const string ColumnName = "Message";
    private const string InputDescription = "Input for IbmMQDestinationAdapter";

    private IManagedConnection connection;
    private IQueue queue;
    private ArrayList columnInfos = new ArrayList();
    private bool reRaise = true;
    private  IDTSInput100 messageInput;

    #region ColumnInfo
    private struct ColumnInfo
    {
        public int BufferColumnIndex;
        public string ColumnName;
    }
    #endregion



    private string QueueName
    {
        get { return GetProperty<string>(QueuePropertyName); }
    }

    private int BatchSize
    {
        get { return GetProperty<int>(BatchWriteSize); }
    }

    public override void ProvideComponentProperties()
    {
         TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Executing ProvideComponentProperties");

        //base.ProvideComponentProperties();

        ////Clear out base implementation
        //ComponentMetaData.RuntimeConnectionCollection.RemoveAll();
        //ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.RemoveAll();
        //ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection.RemoveAll();

        //Provide the inital components.
        RemoveAllInputsOutputsAndCustomProperties();
        ComponentMetaData.RuntimeConnectionCollection.RemoveAll();
        ComponentMetaData.UsesDispositions = true;

        SetComponentAttribute();

         messageInput = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.New();
        messageInput.Name = MessageInputName;
        messageInput.Description = InputDescription;
        messageInput.HasSideEffects = true;
        messageInput.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection.IsUsed = true;

        TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Creating InputColCollection");
        IDTSInputColumn100 inCol = messageInput.InputColumnCollection.New();
        TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Setting incol.Name {0}" , ColumnName);
        inCol.Name = ColumnName;

        CreateInputAndMetaDataColumns(messageInput);


        DtsExtensions.CreateCustomProperty(ComponentMetaData.CustomPropertyCollection.New(), QueuePropertyName, "The name of the queue to connect to", true, "QueueName");
        //DtsExtensions.CreateCustomProperty(ComponentMetaData.CustomPropertyCollection.New(), BatchWriteSize, "Maximum number of messages to dequeue(0=all)", true, 5000);

        //Reserve space for the connection manager
        IDTSRuntimeConnection100 connectionSite = ComponentMetaData.RuntimeConnectionCollection.New();
        connectionSite.Name = ConnectionName;
    }

    public override DTSValidationStatus Validate()
    {
        bool pbCancel = false;

        if (ComponentMetaData.OutputCollection.Count != 0)
        {
        ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, ComponentMetaData.Name, "Unexpected Output found. Destination components do not support outputs",
            "", 0, out pbCancel);
        return DTSValidationStatus.VS_ISCORRUPT;

        }

        if (ComponentMetaData.AreInputColumnsValid == false)
        {
        ComponentMetaData.InputCollection["ComponentInput"].InputColumnCollection.RemoveAll();
        return DTSValidationStatus.VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA;
        }
        ////What about if we have input columns but we have no ExternalMetaData
        ////columns? Maybe somebody removed them through code.
        //IDTSInput100 input = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[MessageInputName];
        //if (DoesEachInputColumnHaveAMetaDataColumnAndDoDatatypesMatch(input.ID) ==false)
        //{
        //    ComponentMetaData.FireError(0, "Validate", "input columns and metadata columns are out of sync. Making call to ReinitializeMetaData", "", 0, out pbCancel);
        //    return DTSValidationStatus.VS_NEEDSNEWMETADATA;
        //}

        return base.Validate();
    }

    private bool DoesEachInputColumnHaveAMetaDataColumnAndDoDatatypesMatch(int inputID)
    {
        IDTSInput100 input = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.GetObjectByID(inputID);
        IDTSExternalMetadataColumn100 mdc;
        bool rtnVal = true;
        foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 col in input.InputColumnCollection)
        {
        if (col.ExternalMetadataColumnID == 0)
        {
            rtnVal = false;
        }
        else
        {
            mdc =
            input.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection[col.ExternalMetadataColumnID];
            if (mdc.DataType != col.DataType || mdc.Length != col.Length ||
            mdc.Precision != col.Precision || mdc.Scale != col.Scale || mdc.CodePage !=
            col.CodePage)
            {
            rtnVal = false;
            }
        }
        }
        return rtnVal;
    }

    public override void OnInputPathAttached(int inputID)
    {
        IDTSInput100 input = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.GetObjectByID(inputID);
        IDTSVirtualInput100 vInput = input.GetVirtualInput();
        foreach (IDTSVirtualInputColumn100 vCol in vInput.VirtualInputColumnCollection)
        {
        this.SetUsageType(inputID, vInput, vCol.LineageID, DTSUsageType.UT_READONLY);
        }
    }

    public override void PreExecute()
    {
        TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "PreExecute");

        IDTSInput100 input = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[MessageInputName];

       // CreateInputAndMetaDataColumns(input );

        TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "PreExecute after getting Inputcollection");
        ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "PreExecute about to loop", "Start loop of columns", null, 0, ref reRaise);
        TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "PreExecute Loop");
        foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 inCol in input.InputColumnCollection)
        {
        ColumnInfo ci = new ColumnInfo();
        ci.BufferColumnIndex = BufferManager.FindColumnByLineageID(input.Buffer, inCol.LineageID);
        ci.ColumnName = inCol.Name;
        TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, " PreExecute columnInfo Name: {0}", inCol.Name);
        columnInfos.Add(ci);
        }

    }

    public override void ReinitializeMetaData()
    {
        IDTSInput100 _profinput = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection[MessageInputName];
        if (_profinput.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection.Count > 0)
        {
        _profinput.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection.RemoveAll();
        }
        if (_profinput.InputColumnCollection.Count > 0)
        {
        _profinput.InputColumnCollection.RemoveAll();
        }
        CreateMetaDataColumns(_profinput);
    }

    private void CreateMetaDataColumns(IDTSInput100 input)
    {
        TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "CreateMetaDataColumns");

        IDTSExternalMetadataColumnCollection100 extCols = input.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection;
        TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Got extCols");

        //IDTSInputColumn100 inCol = messageInput.InputColumnCollection.New();
        //inCol.Name = ColumnName;

        foreach (IDTSInputColumn100 inCol in input.InputColumnCollection)
        {
        TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "For Each ColumnName = {0}", inCol.Name);
        if (inCol.Name == ColumnName)
        {
            TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Create new ExtCol");
            IDTSExternalMetadataColumn100 extCol = extCols.New();
            TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Set them to input col");
            extCol.Name = inCol.Name;
            extCol.ID = inCol.ID;
            extCol.DataType = inCol.DataType;
            extCol.Length = inCol.Length;
            extCol.Precision = inCol.Precision;
            extCol.Scale = inCol.Scale;
            extCol.CodePage = inCol.CodePage;
        }

        }
    }


    public override void AcquireConnections(object transaction)
    {
        if (transaction != null && connection.Configuration.AcknowledgementMode == Acknowledgement.Session)
        {
        ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "AcquireConnections()", "Enlist in transaction", null, 0,
                          ref reRaise);
        //If the connection mode is session and there is a valid transaction then enlist.
        IntPtr pUnk = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(transaction);
        var dtcTrans = (IDtcTransaction)Marshal.GetTypedObjectForIUnknown(pUnk, typeof(IDtcTransaction));
        Transaction managedTrans = TransactionInterop.GetTransactionFromDtcTransaction(dtcTrans);
        managedTrans.EnlistVolatile(this, EnlistmentOptions.EnlistDuringPrepareRequired);
        }

        IDTSRuntimeConnection100 conn = ComponentMetaData.RuntimeConnectionCollection[0];
        connection = (IManagedConnection)conn.ConnectionManager.AcquireConnection(transaction);
        if (connection is IbmMQConnection)
        {
        ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "AcquireConnections()", "Connecting", null, 0, ref reRaise);

        //Connect if not connected
        if (!connection.IsConnected())
            connection.Connect();
        if (connection.IsConnected())
        {
            ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "AcquireConnections()", "Connected.", null, 0, ref reRaise);
            ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "AcquireConnections()", "Connecting to queue", null, 0, ref reRaise);
            queue = new IbmMQQueue(connection) { QueueName = QueueName };
            queue.Open();
        }
        }
    }

    public override void ReleaseConnections()
    {
        if (queue != null)
        queue.Close();

        base.ReleaseConnections();
    }

    //public void CreateExternalMetaDataColumn(IDTSInput100 input, int inputColumnID)
    //{
    //    IDTSInputColumn100 oColumn = input.InputColumnCollection.GetObjectByID(inputColumnID);
    //    IDTSExternalMetadataColumn100 eColumn = input.ExternalMetadataColumnCollection.New();

    //    eColumn.DataType = oColumn.DataType;
    //    eColumn.Precision = oColumn.Precision;
    //    eColumn.Scale = oColumn.Scale;
    //    eColumn.Length = oColumn.Length;
    //    eColumn.CodePage = oColumn.CodePage;

    //    oColumn.ExternalMetadataColumnID = eColumn.ID;
    //}


    public override void ProcessInput(int inputID, PipelineBuffer buffer)
    {
        ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "ProcessInput Jo", "Beginning Process Input", null, 0, ref reRaise);

        if (!buffer.EndOfRowset)
        {

        while (buffer.NextRow())
        {
            ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "ProcessInput()", "Beginning loop of columnns", null, 0,
                              ref reRaise);

            TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Process Input columninfos,count = {0}", columnInfos.Count);
            var message = new Message();
            for (int i = 0; i < columnInfos.Count; i++)
            {

                ColumnInfo ci = (ColumnInfo) columnInfos[i];
                object o = buffer[ci.BufferColumnIndex];
                if (o == null)
                {
                TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "o is null");


                TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "ColumnName: {0} ", ci.ColumnName);
                }
                else
                {
                TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "testing trace {0}: ", "Jo");
                TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "ColumnName: {0}", ci.ColumnName);
                TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Column Value: {0}", buffer[ci.BufferColumnIndex].ToString());
                if (ci.ColumnName == ColumnName)
                {
                    TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Setting MessageContents");
                    message.Contents = buffer[ci.BufferColumnIndex].ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Setting MessageId");
                    message.MessageId = buffer[ci.BufferColumnIndex].ToString();
                }


                }


            }
            queue.Write(message);

            //string messageContents = buffer.GetString(m_BlobColumnIndex);
            //TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Message contents", messageContents);

            //var message = new Message("1", messageContents);
            //ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "ProcessInput()", "Beginning queue write set contents", null, 0,
            //                                  ref reRaise);
            //queue.Write(message);
            ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "ProcessInput()", "after queue write", null, 0, ref reRaise);
            connection.Commit();

        }
        }
    }


    private void SetComponentAttribute()
    {
        var componentAttribute =
        (DtsPipelineComponentAttribute)
        Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(GetType(), typeof(DtsPipelineComponentAttribute), false);
        int currentVersion = componentAttribute.CurrentVersion;

        ComponentMetaData.Version = currentVersion;
        ComponentMetaData.ContactInfo = ContactInfo;
    }

    private T GetProperty<T>(string propertyName)
    {
        foreach (IDTSCustomProperty100 possibleProperty in ComponentMetaData.CustomPropertyCollection)
        {
        if (possibleProperty.Name == propertyName)
        {
            return (T)possibleProperty.Value;
        }
        }
        return default(T);
    }

    #region IEnlistmentNotification Members

    public void Commit(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        ComponentMetaData.FireInformation(0, "Commit(Enlistment enlistment)", "Beginning commit", null, 0, ref reRaise);
        connection.Commit();
        ComponentMetaData.FireProgress("Committed", 100, 0, 0, "IbmMQSourceAdapter", ref reRaise);
        enlistment.Done();
    }

    public void InDoubt(Enlistment enlistment)
    {

    }

    public void Prepare(PreparingEnlistment preparingEnlistment)
    {
        if (connection != null)
        {
        preparingEnlistment.Prepared();
        //  TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Transaction Preparing");
        }
    }

    public void Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)
    {
        connection.Rollback();
        //  TraceLogging.WriteTrace(this, "Rollback Executed");
        ComponentMetaData.FireWarning(0, "Rollback(Enlistment enlistment)", "Rolling back transaction", null, 0);
        enlistment.Done();
    }

    #endregion
    }
    }
```